# Fogbugz Duplicate Cases

Tags: project-management, merge, case, fogbugz

I am using FogBugz free hosting to manage my project bugs, I also have several customers I create custom software for, been using FogBugz to keep everything organized.

Question I have is, there are times where they send me an email with a bug, so I report it in my system and they create it as well, instead of having 2 cases of same bug, would like to merge or link them together, rather not just delete the duplicate.

Is there a way to link them together, maybe like a cross reference or even merge them together?

Comment: You can resolve case with "duplicate" resolution. Then, new text field will appear where you can enter ID of duplicate case.

Comment: Thanks, I actually like that way better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do this.

I was able to add the duplicate cases as a subcase and the primary one as a parent case, that way i can link them together and be able to keep them together.

Answer (score 2):

A FogBugz plugin was recently developed and released by Quarantainenet to solve this problem! It is available for download for a Licensed FogBugz server from the [FogCreek Plugin Gallery](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/plugins/plugin.aspx?ixPlugin=72), and can be enabled for FogBugz On Demand accounts by going to the plugins page, viewing all available plugins and choosing to install the "Case Event Merge" plugin.